# Facebook Messenger camera is extremely dark for no known reason

Tags: photos, facebook-messenger

When I try to take a picture using the Messenger app camera, it is incredibly dark, and I can barely see the photo it takes, even in broad daylight. To take a decent photo, I have to close the app, use my actual camera app, then upload it.

What could be causing this?

I have a HTC Desire 530, with an 8 megapixel camera

Comment: Can you give some more information? Has this issue always existed for you or did it start suddenly? It could be caused by one of the updates to the APP itself.

Comment: @Jordy19 I noticed it after I got a new phone. It's possible this could be due to an update, I just happened to get a new phone at the same time

Comment: Alright, I have not found a similar case about it on Google. What you can do is trying an older version from APKMirror.com.